# How to display icon and content next to each other without using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass, css-selectors

I have this HTML that displays icons on the left, and summary on the right. I wrapped the icons and the summary using a bootstrap class `col-sm-3 col-md-3`. I did this because I wanted to display only four icons per row.If there are more than four icons, then the icons need to move the next row. I put the summary in `col-sm-3 col-md-3` class because I want the text to be next to the icons.

However, I no longer want to use bootstrap, so I am looking at ways to achieve what I want with just CSS.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="coreStuff"> 
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <p>Global warming can result in many serious alterations to the environment, eventually impacting human health. It can also cause a rise in sea level, leading to the loss of coastal land, a change in precipitation patterns, increased risks of droughts and floods, and threats to biodiversity.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I got it to partially work with CSS grid, but let's say there is only one icon, or two icon, in that case this CSS won't work because it creating a wide gap between the icon(s) and the summary. Is there a way to make the summary responsive and dynamically adjust with respective to the icons?

CSS:

```
.theIcons{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.theSummary{
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
<div class="coreStuff"> 
    <div class="icons">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe">1</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe">2</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe">3</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe">4</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe">5</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe">6</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe">7</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe">8</i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-globe">9</i>
    </div>  
    <div class="summary">
        <p>Global warming can result in many serious alterations to the environment, eventually impacting human health. It can also cause a rise in sea level, leading to the loss of coastal land, a change in precipitation patterns, increased risks of droughts and floods, and threats to biodiversity.</p>
    </div>
</div
```

CSS :
(the borders are just to give visual feedback, you can style as per your needs. Also, you might have to tweak the solution based on your own design and layout)

```
.icons, .summary{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.coreStuff { 
  display: flex;
/*  you'll probably want to give some fix width  */
  width: 30em;
}

.icons i {
  border: 1px solid red;
/*   height: 30px; */
/*   width: 30px; */
}

.icons{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns : repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  flex-basis: 30%;
/*   gap: 0.5em; */
}
.summary{
  flex-basis: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean there is an icon for each summary? If that is true you have to change your HTML to be like this

```
<div class="coreStuff"> 
<div class="box">
<i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
<p>your summary </p>
</div>
```

and your css It could be like this :

```
.coreStuff{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
gap:1%
}
.box{
width:24%
display:flex;
gap : 10px ;
}
```